# How to use ffmpeg convert this file,the normal args can't convert it

Tags: video, ffmpeg, conversion

The [Video Link](http://188.166.213.154/9.mp4) is here.

```
$ffmpeg -i 9.mp4 out.mp4
ffmpeg version N-86676-g45dbb40cd1-static http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.1 (Debian 5.4.1-11) 20170519
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-5 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gray --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      55. 67.100 / 55. 67.100
  libavcodec     57.100.102 / 57.100.102
  libavformat    57. 75.100 / 57. 75.100
  libavdevice    57.  7.100 / 57.  7.100
  libavfilter     6. 94.100 /  6. 94.100
  libswscale      4.  7.101 /  4.  7.101
  libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
  libpostproc    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '9.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    artist          : moodyz
    encoder         : Lavf57.75.100
    copyright       : moodyz
  Duration: 00:00:21.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5662 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(jpn): Video: vc1 (Advanced) (vc-1 / 0x312D6376), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 5658 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (vc1 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x3eabba0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x3eabba0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x3eabba0] profile High, level 4.0
[libx264 @ 0x3eabba0] 264 - core 152 r19 ba24899 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=3 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    artist          : moodyz
    copyright       : moodyz
    encoder         : Lavf57.75.100
    Stream #0:0(jpn): Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 29.97 fps, 30k tbn, 29.97 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.100.102 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=29.0 Lsize=      33kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=8254060.6kbits/s speed=0.000122x    
video:32kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 2.640781%
[libx264 @ 0x3eabba0] frame I:1     Avg QP:23.97  size: 32485
[libx264 @ 0x3eabba0] mb I  I16..4: 24.7% 72.0%  3.3%
[libx264 @ 0x3eabba0] 8x8 transform intra:72.0%
[libx264 @ 0x3eabba0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 31.5% 51.4% 4.9%
[libx264 @ 0x3eabba0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 50% 28% 11% 10%
[libx264 @ 0x3eabba0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 58% 19% 17%  1%  1%  1%  1%  1%  1%
[libx264 @ 0x3eabba0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 53% 22%  7%  4%  2%  5%  2%  3%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x3eabba0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 47% 20% 31%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x3eabba0] kb/s:7788.61
```

Original video "Duration: 00:00:21.02",but the output file only "Duration 00:00:00.03".

What args I need to add?

Comment: Seems to be a bug with ffmpeg – the video should contain more data. Do you know where the sample video comes from?

Comment: Yes,it contain more data,I can play it by PotPlayer.The video is a segment,I split the video into 483 segments.Using this cli:"ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -i  input.wmv -f segment -segment_time 20 -vcodec copy -reset_timestamps 1 -map 0:1 %d.mp4"

Comment: It's weird. ffprobe shows the sample as having one packet and yet fast seek `-ss N -i ...` will correctly output 1 frame which corresponds to `N`. ffmbc & mp4box remux the file fine showing 630 frames as the mux count, yet ffmpeg shows the same behaviour with the remuxed file. To the OP, segment to MKV and check. I suspect this has something to do with the vc-1/dvc1 box that ffmpeg writes when muxing VC-1 streams in MP4.